# rvalue reference to temporary declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration, rvalue-reference, rvalue

```
E && e0 = E () ; 
E e1 ;
```

is there any differences between these two cases of object declaration.? ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example :

- The result of `E()` is an rvalue (a prvalue to be exact);
- `e0` is an lvalue, of type `E&&` (rvalue reference to `E`);
- `e1` is also an lvalue, of type `E`;
- `e0`, by binding to the result of `E()`, extends its lifetime from temporary to automatic.

Thus, if following code does not make the difference between `E` and `E&&` (for example, `decltype` would but `auto` wouldn't), they will behave the same.